# How do I populate a select box depending on what was selected on the other select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to populate my 2nd select box with the appropriate values depending on what was selected on the 1st select box.

This is what I have done so far but it's not working.
HTML:

```
    <form id = "step1">
                <p>
                    Creator:
                    <select name="creator" id = "creator">
                        <option></option>
                        <option name = "hello" value = "hello">Hello</option>
                        <option name = "abc"> oiasfn</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Trip Title:
                    <select name="title" id = "title">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                </p>
</form>
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateform();

});

function updateform(){
    document.getElementById("creator").onchange = populatetitle;
}

function populatetitle(){
    var select = document.getElementById("creator");
    if(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = "hello"){
        select.options.add(new Option('Byebye', 'Bye'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you add the value to the 1st select box. You need to change `select.options.add(new Option('Byebye', 'Bye'));` to `select2.options.add(new Option('Byebye', 'Bye'));`

Where

```
var select2 = document.getElementById("title");
```

Another solution is some code that I crafted up. Which does exactly the same thing, but makes it more dynamic.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zjNqP/1/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#creator').change(function () {
        populatetitle();
    });
});

//Set the values for the select boxes
var values = {"hello":
                 {
                     "ByeBye":"Bye",
                     "text":"value",
                     "value":"Bye2",
                 },
              "abc":
                 {
                     "ABC":"text",
                     "text":"value"
                 },
              "selectBox1value":
                  {
                      "SelectBox2Text":"SelectBox2Value"
                  },
              "": //Default case
                  {
                      "text":"value"
                  }
              };

function populatetitle() {
    var firstSelect = $("#creator");
    var secondSelect = $("#title");
    var valuesForSecondSelect = values[firstSelect.val()]; //get values based on 1st selection box
    secondSelect.empty(); // remove old options
    $.each(valuesForSecondSelect, function(key, value) {
        //loop through all values for 2nd box and add them
        secondSelect.append($("<option></option>")
                   .attr("value", value).text(key));
    });
}
```

Comment: so what if i want to use JSON instead? how can that be achieved?

Comment: As long as the JSON follows the same format as values is currently defined just override values. But, if the format is different you'll need to modify populatetitle() to traverse through the JSON data properly

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few problems:

On line `11`, you should use `==` or `===` for equality comparison, but you are mistakenly using `=`:

```
if(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = "hello"){
```

Again on line `13`, you are mistakenly adding the 'Bye' option to the same select, but I assume you want to add it to the `#title` select:

```
document.getElementById("title").options.add(new Option('Byebye', 'Bye'));
```

Also, your code is not idiomatic jQuery. You are using a mixture of jQuery and native DOM APIs which makes your code confusing. Also, IMHO, you can use better names for your functions and variables:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    observeCreator();
});

function observeCreator() {
  $("#creator").change(onCreatorChanged);
}

function onCreatorChanged() {
  var creatorSelect = $(this);
  var titleSelect = $("#title");
  var options;

  if (creatorSelect.val() == "hello") {
     options = $("<option></option><option value='bye'>Bye</option>");
    titleSelect.html(options);
    titleSelect.val("bye");
  } else {
    options = $("<option></option>");
    titleSelect.html(options);
    titleSelect.val("");
  }
}
```

Finally, make sure you do not add the `Bye` option multiple times to the `#title` select if that is not your intention.

Comment: Happy 10K, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

The  problem likely stems from the fact that you're not adding it to the second `select`, but the first.  However, I haven't checked this because since you're already using jquery, you should use it for the change event handler as well.  It will make it much easier.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#creator').on('change', function() {
        var $title = $('#title').empty();
        if ($(this).val() == 'hello') {
            $title.append('<option value="Bye">Bye bye</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/JRUpR/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#creator').change(function () {
        populatetitle();
    });
});

function populatetitle() {
    var firstSelect = document.getElementById("creator");
    var secondSelect = document.getElementById("title");
    if (firstSelect.options[firstSelect.selectedIndex].value === "hello") {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = "Byebye";
        option.value = "Bye";
        secondSelect.add(option, null);
    }
}
```